# In Swift is a lazy instantiator called if the the var is written?

Tags: swift

Here is the Objective-C code I am translating to Swift:

```
@implementation Audio
@synthesize fileCode = _fileCode;

- (NSString *)fileCode
{
    if (!_fileCode)
        _fileCode = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
    return _fileCode;
}

...
```

Here is a start at translating this:

```
class Audio: NSObject {
    var fileID: Int?

    lazy var fileCode = {
        return NSUUID.UUID().UUIDString;
    }

...
```

Assuming that UUID calculation is unnecessarily expensive, I would like to avoid it if necessary.

In Objective-C the use case:

```
Audio bob = [[Audio alloc] init];
bob.fileCode = "CODE";
```

Would not cause the lazy initializer to be called, since the getter skips it.

Can I be assured of this as well for Swift?

Comment: Did you try to test that yourself by setting a breakpoint or adding a print statement inside the method?

Comment: As an aside, your property initialization should be `lazy var fileCode = NSUUID().UUIDString` Swift doesn't use factory methods and you don't want to make the property a closure.

Comment: If you are trying to bypass the lazy-initialiser by assigning a default value from another place, why don't you just declare "normal" property?

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly the definition of `lazy`, from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254):

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used.

Comment: The clarification I am seeking is if assigning a new value to that property counts as "using" it.

Answer (score 1):

I did a test in Swift 2.1.1, and the lazy initializer is **not** called at all if you set the property prior to getting it (which makes perfect sense). My test code is below.

```
var lazyInitializerCalled = false

func getFileCode() -> String {
    lazyInitializerCalled = true
    return "I'm lazy"
}

class Audio {
    lazy var fileCode = getFileCode()

    init() { }
}

var myClass = Audio()

myClass.fileCode = "I'm not lazy" // comment this out to use the lazy initializer

print(myClass.fileCode)

if !lazyInitializerCalled {
    print("We skipped the lazy initializer!")
} else {
    print("We called the lazy initializer!")
}
```